# Como usar um ListView dentro de um ScrollView

Tags: java, android-layout, android-xml

Olá, estou tentando usar um ListView dentro de um ScrollView. O objetivo é funcionar semelhante a outros apps que fazem isso, como o instagram e o jovem nerd. Abaixo do meu comentário vai estar o código em xml e debaixo dele em java.Obrigado

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#212121"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slImageResource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="205dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#FFFFFF"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:selected_padding_left="6dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="6dp"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:shape="oval"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="2dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="2dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

```js
slImages = (SliderLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.slImageResource);

        FSocietySlideView slideView = new FSocietySlideView(getContext());
        slideView.image(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        slideView.setOnSliderClickListener(HomeFragment.this);
        slideView.description("None");
        slImages.addSlider(slideView);

        final ArrayList<FSociety> news = new ArrayList<>();

        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        news.add(new FSociety(getResources(), "None", "None", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        FSocietyAdapter adapter = new FSocietyAdapter(getActivity(),news);

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_test);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Nao esta claro qual sua duvida.. O proprio listview ja tem scroll, porque precisa colocar ele dentro de um scrollView?

Comment: Porque eu quero que todo o layout se movimente. Com apenas a listView, só vou poder movimentar os próprios itens dessa lista. Por isso eu sitei alguns dos apps que fazem isso, para poderem imaginar o que pretendo fazer.

Comment: Ninguém tem uma sugestão ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o ListView dentro de um LinearLayout com altura fixa. Assim você poderá colocar o Scroll em toda a Activity e ainda com o Scroll do próprio ListView.